# To power an arduino that isn't always on, should I connect a switch before or after a buck converter?

Tags: power, led-strip

I am adding an RGBW led light bar to the rear hatch of my car. I control the brightness with an Arduino powered with a buck converter, which is connected to the car battery (via an always-hot line that also runs to a window motor controllable with a key in the rear hatch). Since I don't want the leds on all the time, I have an on/off switch that controls when the arduino gets power.

What I'm wondering is this: Should I have the switch on the positive **input** side of the buck converter so that it doesn't isn't always converting power? Or can I have the switch on the **output** side so that the buck converter has 5V ready to go from the moment I turn on the switch?

I imagine if the switch is only controlling the power to the arduino from the output side of the converter I could burn out the converter (no output current for long periods of time) and potentially drain the battery if it's left long enough?

Or maybe this doesn't matter and the arduino can be left on 100% of the time and the switch can simply tell the arduino when to turn on the leds? This doesn't seem like it would be a great idea though given the temperatures can go from -10 to 100 degrees F. And I don't think the arduino would be happy running 24/7...

Comment: the buck won't switch it's output on until it's basically ready to go. this, you don't have to have to worry about "cold starts" giving out a brief erroneous voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.Since it is connected to a battery and the converter uses energy put the switch between the battery and converter.  Depending on your vehicle the allowable leakage current is in the range of 10 to 100 mA. This leakage current has a big impact on how long you can leave the car such as the airport while on a trip. This will add to that leakage current decreasing the time between battery charging. Also do you have some protection for the converter to protect from all the nasty things you will see in an automotive electrical environment such as reverse battery, load dump, and many more? You might also want to check with your local authorities about your lighting, in some areas it would not be legal.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any protection on the converter, would you recommend a diode? I'm not too worried about much strange behavior (or legality) as it's basically an interior light to light up the cargo area when the hatch is open

Comment: A diode wouold work just fine but it should be at least 100V and capable of the surge current you would get if a transient occurs. With LEDs assume some 60V transients may occur.